# How do I sort a list using .NET 2.0 (similar to LINQ OrderBy)

Tags: vb.net, linq, sorting, compare, ienumerable

How can I rewrite this function so it will do the same like now, but without using LINQ?

```
Public Function GetAllConnections() As IEnumerable(Of Connection)
    Return GetAllTcpConnections.Concat(GetAllUdpConnections) _
                               .OrderBy(Function(Conn) Conn.Proto) _
                               .ThenBy(Function(Conn) Conn.State)
End Function
```

Both functions, GetAllTcpConnections and GetAllUdpConnections return a `As List(Of Connection`)

I basiclly need this function to do the same thing like now, without using LINQ, so I can also use it with Net Framework 2.0

Comment: You could use [LinqBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx) to get (partial) LINQ support in .NET 2.0.

Comment: I thought about doing it without LINQ and also without LINQ-Bridge. Isn't it possible to accomplish the same thign with IComparer somehow? :/

Comment: I think the code will look a lot less cleaner if you try to write it without LINQ. I don't see much of a problem using LinqBridge. Do you have a particular reason not wanting to use it?

Comment: Well, I personally don't like Linq, I want it work without LINQ, then I can understand it better, personally. How would you do it with List.Sort() is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my comment, I would suggest you to use [LINQBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx), however you don't seem to want to use LINQ.

Below is an example how you could solve this. First do the concat yourself and afterwards use a custom comparer to sort.

```
Class ConnectionComparer
    Implements IComparer(Of Connection)

    Public Function Compare(x As Connection, y As Connection) As Integer Implements System.Collections.Generic.IComparer(Of Connection).Compare
        ' Assuming that "Nothing" < "Something"
        If x Is Nothing AndAlso y Is Nothing Then Return 0
        If x Is Nothing AndAlso y IsNot Nothing Then Return 1
        If x IsNot Nothing AndAlso y Is Nothing Then Return -1

        Dim protoCompare As Integer = x.Proto.CompareTo(y.Proto)
        If protoCompare = 0 Then
            Return x.State.CompareTo(y.State)
        Else
            Return protoCompare
        End If
    End Function
End Class

Function GetAllConnections() As IEnumerable(Of Connection)
    ' Concat
    Dim connections As List(Of Connection) = GetAllTcpConnections()
    connections.AddRange(GetAllUdpConnections())
    ' Custom comparer to compare first "Proto" and then "State"
    Dim comparer As New ConnectionComparer()
    connections.Sort(comparer)

    Return connections
End Function
```

Note that the above example will output the same as the code using LINQ. However under the hood, the implementation is quite different (using Lists instead of IEnumerable (LINQ)).